# How can I remove this error with build.gradle (module app) in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I am getting the error in following line 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

And I am getting this in description for the above error.
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.1.0, 26.1.0.)

I uninstalled Android Studio twice & again installed it again.
But it didn't help.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'  
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is made by different jar, just use my two method, the error is resolved

1. Revise the picasso

   ```
   implementation('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'){
       exclude group: 'com.android.support'
   }
   ```
2. Add below item into build.gradle

   ```
   implementation ('com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0')
   ```